# Does defining initialize for a singleton class make sense in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, internals

I anticipate that I am not trying to do anything practical here, just trying to understand some deeper Ruby concepts.

Supppose I have the following code

```
class Bookshelf
  @book_qty = 100 # class instance var

  class << self
    attr_accessor :books_qty 
  end

  def initialize
    @book = "This book is in every object as an object instance variable"
  end

  # so far so good, but what happens with...

  def self.initialize   # what would be this called on ?
    puts " and at what step would this be printed, if ever?"
    # I thought it would be printed when the class code is parsed first time,
    # but no
  end

  # or also

  class << self
    def initialize
      puts "same here"
    end
  end

end
```

I know it might not make sense or might be too intricately related on how Ruby internals work, but, if by chance anyone has been puzzled too by this and knows the answer... please share it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no purpose to defining `initialize` for the singleton class (whether you use `def self.` or `class << self`). `initialize` is only called by `Class#new` and...

```
Bookshelf.singleton_class.new
# TypeError: can't create instance of singleton class
```

that's not allowed.

If you want code to be executed the first time a class is parsed, just put it in the class

```
class Bookshelf
  puts "class defined!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it does make sense to define a custom constructor, but I wouldn't call the method `initialize`, since the instance method you override to customise initialisation is also called `initialize`. That would be a little confusing.

> def self.initialize   # what would be this called on ?

If you define a method like this, you can invoke it by sending the method directly to the class:

```
Bookshelf.initialize
```

Same thing applies for methods defined inside `class << self`.

As mentioned, it does make sense to define custom constructors for a class. Sometimes just for readability's sake:

```
class Bookshelf
  attr_accessor :book_qty

  def self.with_quantity(quantity)
    new(quantity)
  end

  def initialize(quantity)
    self.book_qty = quantity
  end
end
```

Now you could instantiate a Bookshelf like this:

```
bs = Bookshelf.with_quantity 100
bs.quantity # => 100
```

You actually call `.new` on the singleton class of `Bookshelf`. And `#initialize` is basically just a hook for the instance to tweak its initialisation.

**How you could access class instance variables**

```
class Bookshelf
  @book_qty = 1000
  class << self
    attr_accessor :book_qty
  end
end

Bookshelf.book_qty # => 1000
Bookshelf.book_qty = 2000
Bookshelf.book_qty # => 2000
```

Comment: Wait a second but isn't that `def initialize(quantity) ... end` only called when creating an object instance of the Bookshelf class with Bookshelf.new ?

Comment: Yes, `Bookshelf.new` calls `#initialize` on its instances. So if you call `.new` from your own constructor (`.with_quantity` in the example above), you achieve the same thing.

Comment: But I didn't want to create a new object to implement this functionality. ie. to modify the quantity on the class instance variable. I wanted it to not assume you were creating a new objects out of it but still modify the book quantity arbitrarily on the singleton class, makes sense?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. I updated the answer with how I would do that. You can also define accessors for class instance variables.

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm basically just cruising around to discover things, I found your first example very interesting even though it was not actually was I was looking for.
To recap it: we have a class Bookshelf which - when we call with_quantity class method - instantiates a new object off that same Bookshelf class (as if we had done b = Bookshelf.new) through the initialize method, which at the same time updates the book_qty class instance variable in the class, right?
The second example is self explanatory :)

Comment: Yes =). Well, I didn't update a class instance variable in the first example (it's a usual instance variable), but the second example describes how you'd update the class one. Keep on discovering! =)

Comment: Let's clarify this last point and I'll let you go ;) ! Inside #initialize you used self.book_qty but you could also have simply used @book_qty right? Does it make any difference at all or is it just for readability sake? Also, self.book_qty works because initialize it's called on the object, so self refers to the object thus we get an instance variable. Correct? Please just send tell me to go read the documentation if I am wrong, you did already a lot! :)

Comment: This answer really has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I have to agree it did not pinpoint what I was asking. I upvoted it because it was helpful, at least to me, to understand even more about Ruby, but I agree that I can't accept it as the right answer...

Comment: @jj_ Yes, you could also write `@book_qty = 100`. I personally prefer using the setter, because you can override it etc. But for the example above it doesn't really matter.  @Max Yes you're right. I didn't understand the question at first, but I'll leave it since @jj_ finds it useful.